# Programmatically launch UIWebView Keyboard

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, ios5.1

Javascript n00b here, this question has been asked before but no straight forward answer was given.

I am trying to launch the keyboard for an editable UIWebView when the view loads.

So far I have the following code

in index.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
         <script Language="text/javascript">
         function showKeyBoard(){
            document.forms['myform'].elements['mytextfield'].focus();
         }
    </script> 
    </head>

    <body OnLoad="document.myform.mytextfield.focus();">
        <form name="myform">
           <textarea type="text" name="mytextfield" cols="40">Tap here to enter text</textarea>
        </form>
    </body>    
    </html>
```

In my view controller I have:

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
    }
```

The same view controller is also the webView's delegate with the following code:

```
      -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView 
      {
           [aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"showKeyBoard()"];
      }
```

Is there anything wrong with my java script or iOS?

The textarea is not necessary for the app I only included it to have a focus-able form element.

I am open to any solution that will get the UIWebView keyboard to launch when the view loads. I have been trying to work out a solution for weeks and I've gotten no where.

Edit: The focus works when I open index.html with a web browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting in iOS 6, you can set [aWebView setKeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction:NO].